# PHP script to handle multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a php script that I can direct to in Windows Task scheduler because I need this job to run every 15 mintues and insert in a database table.

My issue currently is that I have a working query in MySQL Workbench, but for privilege reasons I now need to select data from a table on a read only database and insert it into a table in our production database (different host IP).

Basically, right now I'm selecting from readTable on host 1 and inserting to writeTable on host 1. However, I need to select/join from readTable on host 1 and insert on writeTable on host 2, if that makes sense.

The problem: I don't know how to use multiple db connections like that in a php file, and I couldn't even find a way to do it in workbench.

Here's the php code with query:

```
        <?php 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    $servername2 = "localhost";
    $username2 = "username";
    $password2 = "password";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    // Check connection2
    if ($conn2->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT 
                         c.extension as Extension
                        ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
                        , sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                        , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                        , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound
                        , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inbound
                        , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
                        , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
                      --  , NOW()
                          FROM cdrdb.session a
                          LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                           ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                             LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
                              ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                               WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                               AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
                          group by c.extension");

    foreach ($data as $d) {

    mysqli_query($conn2, "Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report )   
                            ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound)
                  , Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls), Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), Time_of_report = values(NOW())");
    }

     ?>
```

Is it possible to create multiple connections and dictate which ones to use in each part of that query?

Comment: Your script is only making 1 connection (as defined in `$conn`). Define another connection (e.g. `$conn2`) and then reference that when making a query, e.g. (`mysqli_query($conn2, "..."));`

Comment: But if I make 2 connections, can I reference both of them? My query is selecting from one database and inserting to another

Comment: Do you mean reference them both in *one query*, or in *separate queries*? The first is impossible but the latter is possible, i.e. you can select from one database, then insert to another.

Comment: I was hoping to one query, but I can select all from the first one where current date is today and the extension matches. But would I then need to store those results somehow and pass them to be used in an UPSERT statement for the second db

Comment: I've posted an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a connection to your first server:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Make a connection to your second server - defined in a separate variable:

```
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);
```

You can get data (`SELECT`) from the first server, e.g.

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ...");
```

Then use that data - held in `$data` - to write (`INSERT`) into the database on the second server, e.g.

```
mysqli_query($conn2, "INSERT ...");
```

You will of course need a loop to cycle through `$data` and bind the appropriate values in the query. In pseudo-code....

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    // $d is an array of rows from the query done on the first server. 
    // Because you're in a loop you can deal with this data 1 row at a time and do whatever you want with it
    // e.g. write it to the second server's database...
    mysqli_query($conn2, "INSERT INTO some_table(v1, v2) VALUES('".$d['v1']."', '".$d['v2']."') ");
}
```

*I use PDO and am unfamiliar with the `mysqli_query` syntax. You may need to bind the parameters (as you do in PDO) rather than reference them in the query. But the principle of what I've written is the same - you loop through the data obtained from the first server, and write it to the second server inside a loop. This lets you deal with each row of data coming from the query on the first server.*

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! I just need to refine my code and then I'll be able to test it by running the script in task scheduler. I also meant to mention, this is just local so I didn't have to worry about injections or anything but I do appreciate the note on PDO

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd strongly recommend you pay attention to injection, even if it is just local. The reason I wrote that my last code sample was "pseudo-code" is because you should never write it in that way where you're just inserting values directly into the query - as that is where injection attacks can come from. PDO makes that a lot easier with bound parameters, but I'm not sure what the options are in `mysqli_` for this. But please look into it for your own sake :)

Comment: So I updated my code to reflect that answer slightly, but I have a confusion on the foreach loop. You can see in my insert statement that I'm inserting and updating on duplicate key so I have value for each row, and then in Time_Of_Report I need to insert a NOW() timestamp. How exactly should I be modifying that for data?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do. The code doesn't look right though because you haven't referenced `$d` anywhere, and that is the source data from the first database, at least once it's inside your `foreach`

Comment: That's my question is how to use $d in my insert since I have multiple Values, and not just one values string

Comment: `$d` is an array of all the data in *one row* of your `SELECT` query from the first server. If you put in `var_dump($d); die;` and run it, you'll see what that array looks like - it has ALL the values in it from the `SELECT`. You can then use them where needed, e.g. `$d['some_column_name']`. How you bind them to the query is something you'll have to look up as I don't know what the syntax for `mysqli_` is. I know it for PDO but it's not the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've just started applying the $d variable to the value within each value set?parenthesis and I think I'm on the right track now

Answer (score 2):

Sure is that possible, but you have to bind it. If you want to use selfmade connections (not over a framework) then you have to build multiple connections like ....

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$servername2 = "localhost";
$username2 = "username";
$password2 = "password";

// Create connection
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Then you can use each connection with accessing the right $conn or $conn2 variable.

Comment: That makes sense, but one thing (sorry, I'm just a bit confused): If my one query posted above is selecting from one and inserting/updating in another connection, how can I declare both connections in the query?

Comment: That isnt possible in my view. Then you have to select first from one connection and then inserting it with the second connection.

if you have multiple rows from the selecting database, then you have to loop for inserting (single or bulk inserts).

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password); // connection 1
$conn2 = new mysqli($host, $username, $password); // connection 2
```

user $conn1 and $conn2 alternatively as per your purpose...